# Is there anything to be learned from the spectrum of a cohomology ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Given some topological space, $X$, is there any benefit to studying $Spec(H^*(X))$, or is everything we care about already available "in the algebra"?

As $H^*$ is a graded ring, does this question change if we instead look at $Proj(H^*(X))$?

I have so far found a few articles dealing with the spectrum of cohomology rings of varieties, but nothing to do with topological spaces, nor the Proj constriction.

Comment: The first three results [here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=spectrum+of+cohomology+ring) are interesting and quite well known. I am not aware of anything at the level of generality you mention however.

Comment: $H^* (X)$ is not always a commutative ring, so how do you propose to apply $\operatorname{Spec}$ or $\operatorname{Proj}$ to it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I mean in the cases where it is possible to talk about Spec and Proj.

Comment: In fact, I believe that if H* is graded-commutative we can still make these constructions work, but only (I think) if we swap the topological spaces for topological groups. See :  http://library.msri.org/books/Book51/files/01benson.pdf

Comment: AFAIK this POV is more useful in equivariant cohomology. For example, in the context of localization theorems it's natural (at least) to view $H_G(X)$ as a sheaf over $\operatorname{Spec}H_G(pt)$. See also _Quillen. The Spectrum of an Equivariant Cohomology Ring_ and _Goresky,  MacPherson. On the Spectrum of the Equivariant
Cohomology Ring_...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is yes. For example, $\text{Spec }H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty})$ (here the cohomology is concentrated in even degree so there is no issue with applying $\text{Spec}$ in the classical sense) can be identified with the formal affine line. The group structure on $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ given by tensoring line bundles induces a group scheme structure on the formal affine line which is the structure of the formal additive group. This is the beginning of a long story in [chromatic homotopy theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_homotopy_theory) connecting homotopy theory with formal groups.

The next example is to replace ordinary cohomology with K-theory, where we get the formal multiplicative group. Now it's natural to wonder if we can find cohomology theories where we get more exotic ($1$-dimensional, commutative) formal groups such as the formal groups attached to elliptic curves, which is part of the story of [elliptic cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_cohomology). There are lots of other parts of this story as well; see, for example, [Quillen's theorem on MU](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Quillen%27s+theorem+on+MU).

Regarding the complaints in the comments about commutativity, probably a better behaved invariant involves thinking about the derived algebraic geometry of something like $\text{Spec } C^{\bullet}(X)$. [DAG XIII](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/DAG-XIII.pdf) explains something like this.

Comment: +1 for mentioning DAG XIII. It’s a beautifully written exposé on the derived algebraic geometry of cochains which not a lot of people seem to know about (even almost 9 years after this answer was written).