# Topological properties of cohomology rings

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have read this question [Is there anything to be learned from the spectrum of a cohomology ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561143/is-there-anything-to-be-learned-from-the-spectrum-of-a-cohomology-ring). But it seems more focused on the applications of $\mathrm{Spec}(H^*(X;R))$ rather than its topological properties. Which is why I am posting this as a separate question.

I was told that the Zariski topology for a $Z_2$ graded ring (like the cohomology ring defined with the cup product) is homeomorphic to the Zariski topology over its even graded (and so commutative) subring. I see how this should work by mapping primes in the whole ring to the intersection of it and the even graded subring.

With this we get $\mathrm{Spec}(H^*(X;R))\cong \mathrm{Spec}(\bigoplus_{k\text{ even}}H^k(X;R))$ which defines an affine scheme by definition so higher order cohomologies vanishes as shown here in the stacks project https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XB.

I was wondering if this is enough to conclude $\mathrm{Spec}(H^*(X;R)\cong X$? (I'm just studying algebraic topology so I'm not familiar with sheafs,sheaf cohomology and the sort and I'm worried since stacks project seems to reference that maybe this step is wrong.)

Provided this is even right, is this a known result in literature? Where could I read more about this?

Comment: What does the symbol $\cong$ mean in your fourth paragraph? (Oh, and the `\bigotimes` should probably be `\bigoplus` in paragraph 3.)

Comment: Have you tried any examples? For instance, does Spec look different if $X=S^2$ vs. $X=S^4$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Mariano my main question here seems totally wrong (too much wishful thinking I suppose) but I'll read up on the topics you mentioned they seem interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With this we get $\mathrm{Spec}(H^*(X;R))\cong \mathrm{Spec}(\bigotimes_{k\text{ even}}H^k(X;R))$

You need to take the direct sum here.

> I was wondering if this is enough to conclude $\mathrm{Spec}(H^*(X;R)) \cong X$?

No, this is not even close to being true, for multiple reasons. For example if $X$ is any finite-dimensional connected manifold then $H^0(X, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$ and the higher $H^i$ are nilpotent, so $\text{Spec } H^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{R})$ consists of a single point. Generally speaking the cohomology ring is very far from being a complete invariant even up to homotopy, let alone up to homeomorphism.

Comment: Oh ok thanks your help. I really should have checked an example first